# Tkinter grid in multiple frames and potential impact of ttk widgets

Tags: tkinter

This is my first question. Please let me know if there is anything that I need to change.

So I am making a program for ordering food using tk and ttk.
This is my design.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGviF.png

As the header will be in 3 different pages/views, it has its own frame. The content of different pages are in their own frames too. I am having problems with positioning the widgets using `grid`. I am not sure whether `grid` is for the whole window (all frames share the same grid), or each frame has its own grid system.
Following is my code. I have tried my best to make it as distilled as I can.

```
class Header(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        f1button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="F1Button1")
        f1button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        f1button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="F1Button2")
        f1button2.grid(column=3, row=0)


class Homepage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        f2button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="F2Button1")
        f2button1.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)
        f2button2 = ttk.Button(text="F2Button2")
        f2button2.grid(column=1, row=2)
        f2button3 = ttk.Button(text="F2Button3")
        f2button3.grid(column=2, row=2)
        f2button4 = ttk.Button(text="F2Button4")
        f2button4.grid(column=3, row=2)


class root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_frames()
    def create_frames(self):
        header = Header(self)
        header.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
        home = Homepage(self)
        home.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=4)
```

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AejTc.png, where F1 and F2 correspond to `Header` and `Homepage`.
My goal is to have a gap that is 2 buttons wide between F1Button1 and F1Button2, and have F2Button1 directly above the middle of F2Button2 and F2Button3, and align the left side of F2Button4 with the left side of F1Button2. Goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj8M9.png.

It would be hugely helpful if you can help me out.

Comment: You can use `grid` on all frames to put the frames within the window and the frames themselves will have their own `grid` to put the widgets inside it at desirable locations. And Beside this you can use `place` and `grid` or `place` and `pack` together but can never use `grid` with `pack` for your problem `grid` seems the best option.But i think you need to set `columnspan = 2` when using `grid` on `F2Button1`.

Comment: _"I am not sure whether grid is for the whole window (all frames share the same grid), or each frame has its own grid system."_ - each frame has its own grid system.

Comment: It is more easier to lay out those buttons inside *same container* using `grid()` to achieve your goal.